# Privace Policy Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, privacy-policy

How can i add a link to a privacy policy in the developer dashbaord for the chrome web store?

I have published a chrome-extension but i can't add a privacy policy anywhere.

Thanks
Oli

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found it:

1. Goto Chrome Web Store Developer Dashbaord
2. DONT SELECT YOUR EXTENSION. Select "Account" on the menu on the left (probably needs to be expanded
3. you will find a designated field there.